# Issue connection to SQL from PHP

Tags: sql-server, firewall

I've got a Windows workstation which I am successfully able to connect to a SQL 2012 Server over ODBC using the servers IP address.

When I start php 5.4 built in web server and try connect to the same server I am getting a server unknown  error.

My questions are;

- Could this be a firewall issue as I am using port 8080?
- Does this point towards a possible programming issue I should look into further?
- Do I still use the same port I use via ODBC?

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server use port 1433. Verify this port in your firewall and verify your PHP if module of sql server(MSSQL) is enabled.

You can create this file to see if the module is active:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: 1433 is open as I said in my post that I am able to connect fine from the same workstation.

Comment: Ok. Can you show your code of connection? And can you show result of phpinfo?   If you can access por 8080 and the only problem is with the connection with database, this problem is in your code.